# Pass a string between activities

Tags: android, string, android-activity

Hi i want to pass a string through two ativities I've been looking for it in another answers and tried this one:

```
public class GlobalVars extends Activity {
private static String winename;

public static String getWineName(){
    return winename;
}
public static void setWineName(String s){
    winename=s;
}
```

}

And set the string in activity 1 as this:

```
EditText searchbox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.buscarmainText);
String searchb=searchbox.getText().toString();
GlobalVars.setWineName(searchb);
```

But, when I call the getWineName method in activity 2 it seems that the string winename is empty, is called like this:

```
public String sbuscar=GlobalVars.getWineName();
```

Don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You should pass the String via `Intent`.

Comment: don't do it like that. use intents.

Comment: Also tried and my string is still empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to pass string between activities with intents

In your first activity class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, activity2.class);
i.putExtra("KEY",YourData);
```

In next activity class

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString("KEY");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! think it should be on the oncreate method. Now when I want to call the value string in a overriden method it says that value can't be resolved to a variable please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You should put your global vars on a holder class like this.

```
public class GlobalVars {
     public static final String KEY_WINENAME = "winename";
     private static HashMap<String, String> globalVars = new HashMap<String, String>();

     public static String getGlobalVariable(String key) {
         return globalVars.get(key);
     }
}
```

Then from any component from your app you can make a call to `GlobalVars.getGlobalVariable(GlobalVars.KEY_WINENAME);`

If you just want to pass the String from one activity to the next one you should use an Intent as Ram kiran has answered. Usually it's the best practice.

Also you should look at where this piece of code is getting called:

```
EditText searchbox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.buscarmainText);
String searchb = searchbox.getText().toString();
GlobalVars.setWineName(searchb);
```

For instance, if you change the orientation you may be not maintaining the EditText state, so that the text inside it get empty again and your code is called again emptying the variable. If you are unsure put a log line inside `setWinename()` to check if it's been called twice.